# Rails - Unable to use gem in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roo-gem

I am attempting to use the [Roo gem](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) to parse a spreadsheet file in my Rails controller. I have added the appropriate line to my `Gemfile` and ran the `bundle` command. Here is the line in my controller where everything breaks:

```
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filepath)
```

I receive an error: `uninitialized constant MyController::Roo`. I then added the following line to the top of my controller file (as specified in the Roo readme):

```
require 'roo'
```

Now I get a different error: `Error during failsafe response: cannot load such file -- roo`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you bundle and restart your server?

Comment: @fbelanger Doh! I bundled but didn't restart my server. That did the trick. This is my first Rails project so that isn't a habit yet. If you want to post that as an answer I can mark it so you get the points. Thanks!

Comment: Haha welcome to the Rails community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you bundle and restart your server?

Adding gems, modifying app/config files or app/lib files require a server restart :)